# Limitar número de decimales en PHP sin redondear

Tags: php, html

Tengo un pequeño código que hace cierto cálculo y como saben si se imprimen decimales en `PHP` salen muchos, lo que quiero es limitar este numero a 5 decimales.

Trate de usar `round` y aunque con esto se puede especificar un número máximo de decimales también los redondea y no, yo solo quiero un numero de decimales sin que se redondee el resultado.

Por ejemplo:

El resultado lanza:

```
4.6472883
```

Y lo que necesito es:

```
4.64728 (5 decimales)
```

Lo que `round` hace es:

```
4.64729
```

Este es la pequeña parte que hace el calculo por si les es de utilidad

```
//$l_value: es un valor que ingresa el usuario
//$l_mam y $l_ang: son valores ya definido

$to_m = $l_value*$l_mam;
$l_r = $to_m/$l_ang;
echo"<div class='in_val_res' >&nbsp;&nbsp;".round($l_r,5)." unidades</div>";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes usar la función nativa `bcdiv`.

[bcdiv](http://es.php.net/manual/es/function.bcdiv.php) divide dos números de precisión arbitraria con el agregado que te permite recortar el resultado a una escala determinada sin redondear.

```
string bcdiv ( string $left_operand , string $right_operand [, int $scale = 0 ] )
```

Si la división es entre `1` entonces el resultado siempre es el número pero usas la escala para recortar a tu gusto.

Ejemplo

```
$valor = 100.56789;

$data1 = bcdiv($valor, '1', 1);
$data2 = bcdiv($valor, '1', 2);
$data3 = bcdiv($valor, '1', 3);
$data4 = bcdiv($valor, '1', 4);

echo "$data1<br/>";
echo "$data2<br/>";
echo "$data3<br/>";
echo "$data4<br/>";
```

Resultado

```
100.5
100.56
100.567
100.5678
```

Comment: Gracias a TODOS por la respuesta, esta me ha funcionado bien desconocía esa función ! GRACIAS :)

Answer (score 1):

Multiplicarlo y dividirlo por la cantidad de decimales que quieras. (1->10 | 2->100 | ...)

Aunque usemos floor (que es para el redondeo), gracias a la multiplicacion y division consigues el resultado deseado.

```
<?php

$numero=15.26569874;

$resultado = floor(($numero*1000))/1000;

print_r($resultado);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si existirá una función específica, supongo que si... pero puedes "fabricar" un truncamiento "artesanal". Multiplicar el numero para correr la "coma" hacia la derecha (por ejemplo por 100000) y tomas la parte entera de ese resultado y ese número lo vuelves a dividir por 100000...
No se, se me ocurre... 
Por ahí sirve la idea...

```
function truncateFloat($number, $digitos)
 {
$multiplicador = 100000;
$resultado = ((int)($number * $multiplicador)) / $multiplicador;
return number_format($resultado, $digitos);

 }
```

Comment: Llegué a la misma conclusión. Por cierto, puedes usar [`intval()`](http://php.net/intval) para conseguir la parte entera, no hace falta hacer el _casting_.

Comment: Pon de donde lo has sacado ;P http://vicmandev.blogspot.com.es/2011/04/truncar-un-decimal-n-digitos-sin.html

Answer (score 0):

Como comentan en otra respuesta lo más fácil seria hacer un truncado, en mi caso yo lo haría de la siguiente manera, con la funcion intval() y pow ( o doble asterisco ** ):

```
<?php

function truncar($numero, $digitos)
{
    $truncar = 10**$digitos;
    return intval($numero * $truncar) / $truncar;
}

echo truncar(15.26569874, 0); // 15

echo truncar(15.26569874, 4); // 15.2656

echo truncar(15.26569874, 5); // 15.26569
```